# Why can't I see my (localhost) cookie being stored in Electron app?

Tags: cookies, electron

I have an Angular app using Electron as the desktop wrapper. And there's a *separate* Django backend which provides HTTP APIs to the Electron client.

So normally when I call the login API the response header will have a `Set-Cookie` field containing the `sessionId`. And I can clearly see that `sessionId` in Postman, **however, I can't see this cookie in my Angular app (Dev tools of Electron).**

After some further debugging I noticed a warning sign beside my `Set-Cookie` in dev tools. It said that the cookie is blocked due to the `SameSite` being set to `Lax`. So I found a way to modify the server code to return a None samesite (together with a `Secure` property; I'm using HTTP):

```
# settings.py
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

which did work (and the warning sign is gone) but the cookie is still not visible.

So what's the problem here? Why can't (and How can) I see that cookie so as to make sure that the login works in the actual client, not just Postman?

(btw, now both ends are being developed in `localhost`.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to worry. A good way to check if it works is to **actually make a request that requires login** (after the API has been Postman tested) and see if the desired data are returned. If so, you are good to go (especially when the warning is gone).

If the `sessionId` cookie is saved it should automatically be included in the request. *Unless there's something wrong with the cookie's path; but a `/` path would be fine.*

**Why is the cookie not visible**: it's probably due to the separation of front and back ends. In Electron, the pages are typically some local HTML files, as one common step during configuration is to probably modify `loadURL` or something like that in `main.js`, for instance:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/your-project/index.html`);
```

So the "site" you are accessing from Electron can be considered as local filesystem (which has no domain and hence no cookie at all), and you should see an empty `file://` entry in `dev tools -> application -> storage -> cookie`. It doesn't mean a local path containing all cookies of the Electron app. Although your backend may be on the same local machine, you are accessing as `http://` instead of `file://` so the browser (Electron) will treat it as an actual web server.

Therefore, your cookies should be stored in another entry like `http(s)://localhost` and you can't see it in Electron. *(Note that the same cookie will work in both HTTP and HTTPS)*

If you use Chrome instead to test, you may be able to see it in all cookies. In some cases where the frontend and backend are deployed to the same host you may see the cookie in dev tools. But I guess there're always some reasons why you need Electron to create a desktop app (e.g. Python scripts).

### Further reading

#### Using HTTPS

Although moving to HTTPS does not necessarily solve the original problem, it may be worth doing in order to prevent potential problems and get ready for the publish.

In your case, for the backend, you can use `django-sslserver` as a temporary solution before getting your SSL, but it uses a self-signed certificate and may make your frontend complain.
To fix this, consider adding the following code to the main process:

```
# const { app } = require('electron');

if (!app.isPackaged) {
  app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors');
}
```

Now it provides a good way to distinguish between development (unpacked) and production (packed) and only disables certificate check in development in order to make the code work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE in your config refers to cookie's secure flag, You ll have to set

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

because if this flag is set to True the browser will allow this cookie to be set only if you are using an https connection.

PS: This is just for your localhost. Hopefully you ll be using an Https connection in other environments.

Comment: Yes, you're right. HTTPS is the way to go. But I somehow got it to work before in remote testing with Postman under HTTP with the secure flag set. Now it doesn't work anymore, probably because of software update or whatever. And I've started using HTTPS even in localhost.